# SSRS reports broke after upgrading from 2014 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sql-server-2016

One of my team members upgraded the SSRS and SQL servers from 2014 to 2016. Now, rather than doing an upgrade i.e. use existing databases - they uninstalled 2014 and did a fresh install of 2016 for SQL and SSRS. Due to this our reporting server broke. For the DB part - we attached the existing databases so that part was sorted. For SSRS - we detached the new ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB and attached the existing ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB hoping that it would solve the problem partially at least. After doing that we get an error - "The feature: "Scale-out deployment" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services" whenever we open the Report URL. Can someone please help us? We are blocking some important production reports.

Comment: Check your SSRS configuration manager to ensure that scale-out deployment is not configured. If you use it, you will probably need to re-configure it.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I opened SSRS configuration manager but I cannot see Scale Out Deployment option. After Encryption Keys - I can see Subscription Settings and Power BI Integration options. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Scale out deployment should be available where you select your database. Detailed instructions can be found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159114%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.